# Tableau Filter Challenge

Tags: tableau-api

I have a filter challenge with Tableau 10.5.  I have a dashboard that compares comparable weeks in different years and also needs to roll forward each Monday automatically to the most current week.  So - for instance - this Monday it will need to roll forward showing data for the week number 6 of our school year - and show comparable data for week 6 in previous school years.  I've found a way for the "target week" number to be flagged for each year in the sql server data layer.  The challenge - I need the default filter selection to roll forward automatically to the latest "target week" as flagged in the data layer but still give users the option to choose whichever other week numbers they want in the filter.  I've tried placing the "target week" flag as a context filter but that doesn't help.  Currently I simply re-publish each Monday with the filter reset to the next week but I'd like to automate.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think [this article](https://interworks.com/blog/ksloan/2015/03/06/how-set-tableau-dashboard-filters-automatically-update-most-recent-date/) addresses it. Basically, create a True/False calculated field that is True for the current week. Drop it on the filter shelf and add Week too, then in the filter options for the Week filter, select Speical > All Dates to be able to go back in time.

Comment: And filter to True on your new calculated field.